# Can a bitcoin address be duplicated?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm new to this site. A few years ago I got a bitcoin wallet address but honestly never did anything after that but think there is a few dollars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have the private key or seed words leading to that address saved somewhere, there is no feasible way to recreate it.

Comment: Thank you. Excuse my ignorance, what is seed words?

Comment: Seed words are a set of words that can recreate all addresses in your wallet; depending on how old your wallet was, it may predate this process, in which case you would need 1 private key for each address